# ANN Fuel Consumption Prediction Model

Tags: python, neural-network, regression, artificial-intelligence

I am writing a code for an multi-layer perceptron neural network model to predict brake specific fuel consumption using the 4 variables (torque, speed, volumetric efficiency, and fuel mass flow rate) and conduct a global sensitivity analysis on this model. Can someone verify if this is correct?

```
### Read the data ###

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Irish\Desktop\TEST BED DATA\Scaled Gasoline Data.xlsx")
data.head()


### Separate the features (input) and target (output) ###

X = data[['Torque', 'EngSpd', 'FuelMassFlwRate', 'VE']]
y = data['BSFC']

### Splitting the data without random state ###

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Determine the number of features for each set
total_data = X.shape[0]
train_data = int(total_data * 0.7)  # 70% for training, value is then converted to an integer using int()
test_data = int(total_data * 0.15)   # 15% for testing
val_data = total_data - train_data - test_data  # Remaining for validation

# Split the data manually
X_train = X[:train_data]
X_test = X[train_data:train_data + test_data]
X_val = X[train_data + test_data:]

y_train = y[:train_data]
y_test = y[train_data:train_data + test_data]
y_val = y[train_data + test_data:]

print("X_train:")
print(X_train)
print("\nX_test:")
print(X_test)
print("\nX_val:")
print(X_val)
print("\ny_train:")
print(y_train)
print("\ny_test:")
print(y_test)
print("\ny_val:")
print(y_val)


### Build the ANN regression model ###
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()

# Defining the 1st hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=8, input_dim=4, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

# Defining the 2nd hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=16, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

# Defining the 2nd hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=32, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

# Defining the output layer
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))


### Define custom R-squared metric ###
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from keras import backend as K

def r_squared(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true)))
    return 1 - SS_res / (SS_tot + K.epsilon())

### Compile the model with the Adam optimizer and R-squared as a metric ###
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[r_squared])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

### Plot training and validation loss ###
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

### Evaluate the model on the test set ###
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

# Print the Mean Squared Error and R-squared on the test set
print(f'Mean Squared Error on Test Set: {test_results[0]}')
print(f'R-squared on Test Set: {test_results[1]}')

# Print training and validation accuracy on train and val sets
print(f'Mean Squared Error on Training Set: {history.history["loss"][-1]}')
print(f'Mean Squared Error on Validation Set: {history.history["val_loss"][-1]}')

# Predictions on training set
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
r2_train = r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)

# Predictions on validation set
y_validate_pred = model.predict(X_val)
r2_validate = r2_score(y_val, y_validate_pred)

# Print R-squared values
print(f'R-squared on training set: {r2_train}')
print(f'R-squared on validation set: {r2_validate}')

### Sensitivity Analysis ###
import SALib
from SALib import sample
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol
import SALib.sample.saltelli

# 1 Define parameter file
parameter_dict = { 'num_vars': 4,  # Number of input parameters
    'names': ['Torque', 'EngSpd', 'FuelMassFlwRate', 'VE'],
    'bounds': [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]  # Ranges for each input parameter
}

# 2 Generate sample
model_input = SALib.sample.saltelli.sample(parameter_dict, 1024)

# 3 Run model
model_output = Ishigami.evaluate(model_input)
Si = sobol.analyze(parameter_dict, model_output)

# First-order
print(Si['S1'])

# Total-order indices
print(Si['ST'])

# Second-order
print("x1-x2:", Si['S2'][0,1])
print("x1-x3:", Si['S2'][0,2])
print("x1-x4:", Si['S2'][0,3])
print("x2-x3:", Si['S2'][1,2])
print("x2-x4:", Si['S2'][1,3])
print("x3-x4:", Si['S2'][2,3])

# Plot
total_Si, first_Si, second_Si = Si.to_df()
Si.plot()
```

I did not scale my datasets on the code because the values were already normalized (the values are between 0 and 1). However, I'm not certain about my MSE and R_squared results and my sensitivity analysis. How can I make my code clearer or better?

Comment: Checking the correctness of your code is difficult, and I don't think that people on this site will be able to give you the kind of feedback that you are hoping for. We don't have access to the data that you are using and so we have no way of checking the outputs of your code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.